# MySQL, output to file with custom header and footer line

Tags: mysql, command-line

Is it possible to do a MySQL query with the results having a custom first line like "MySQL output" and custom last line, and would you be able to have the last line say something like "This file had 200 rows" for example.

Comment: Yes, this is definitely possible. Generally things like this are best handled by a programming language from which you issue the SQL statement and receive results for formatting. If you provide more detail around your programming environment I'm sure you'll get higher-quality answers.

Comment: that could be done with a store procedure

Comment: I was hoping to do it via command line. I am outputting this to a space separated file and using the RPAD functions. Right now I am using the cat command to merge header and footer to the output, but I was hoping I could do it all in one sql command.